# nonlinear partial differential thermoconductivity 2D equation. numerical solution

Tags: differential-equations

I have to find and plot a numerical solution for this 2d equation:
$$u_{t} = u^{2}(u_{xx}+u_{yy})$$
where $0 \le x \le 10$; $0\le y \le 10$, and $u$ equals to zero everywhere except of circle with the center in (5,5) and radius $1$, where $u(x,y,0)$ equals to some $u_0$. 
As I know, I should choose some grid and use some special scheme to get linear system.
for the linear one I should use the following scheme:
$$\frac{u_{ml}^{n+1} - u_{ml}^n}{\tau} = \frac{u_{m-1,l}^n -2u_{ml}^n+ u_{m+1,l}^n}{h_{x}^2} + \frac{u_{m,l-1}^n -2u_{ml}^n +u_{m,l+1}^n}{h_{y}^2}$$
But what scheme should I use for nonlinear equation?

Comment: What have you tried? This equation is probably wrongly written because it appears to be nonlinear in $u$. The prefactor should most likely be a constant, not $u$.

Comment: No, it shouldn't. The prefactor can be both constant and veriable. There is a common situation where the equation is $u_t = (a(u)u_x)_x$

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Have you tried `NDSolve`? Or do you need to write your own solver?

Comment: How is this related to the software *Mathematica*?

Comment: I have to write a solver using finite difference method. I still didn't try NDSolve.

Comment: As I know, there are a lot of possibilities to write finite difference method in Mathematica. I've seen the example of such solving of some thermoconductivity equation.

Comment: Let me show you the example: http://books-vuzi.narod.ru/olderfiles/1/VICH_MATH_MATHEMATICA.PDF (page 216-218). Unfortunately didn't find it in English

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question belongs to http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/